# Polish space and complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I could not distinguish the exact difference between a Polish space and a complete metric space.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space

I heard that polish space are not necessarily metric spaces. I also heard people call them complete metric space.

Could anyone resolve this point of confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Polish space is a separable topological space that *can be equipped* with a complete metric such that this metric generates the topology that we started with. (We then say that the metric is compatible with the topology.)

Thus by actually equipping a separable topological space with an appropriate metric, it becomes a complete separable metric space, but before there wasn't actually any ambient metric so it was not actually a metric space.

It's helpful to remember that a given topological space can be equipped with many different compatible metrics.

Sometimes people will also abuse terminology and say that a metric space is Polish if it can be equipped with a different metric that makes it complete. For instance, the space $(0,1)$ with the Euclidean topology can be turned into a complete metric space if you use a special metric other than the Euclidean metric, which is nonetheless compatible with the Euclidean topology.

Comment: A remark: $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric (so discrete topology as well) is an example of a complete emtric space that is not Polish, as it is not separable (or equivalently second countable). The second countability does play a big role in the theory, so that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is countably generated, etc.

Comment: A classic characterisation: $X$ is Polish iff there is an embedding $i: X \to [0,1]^\omega$ such that $i[X]$ is a $G_\delta$ in this product.